# Can I use a button inside a SwiftUI sheet view that appears on top of my main SwiftUI view to change a subview inside the main view?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to use a pop up menu (that appears when the user triggers it) to make the users of my app able to change the subview that is shown inside my main view between a `Subview1` and a `Subview2`.

I'm trying to do that using global `Bool` variables that are changed when a button in the view inside the sheet is pressed. Based on those values, the main view should return a different subview

The problem is that when I try to select one option from the view that appears inside the sheet, the action of the `Button` is performed and the sheet is dismissed but the subview displayed by the main view remains unchanged

Is there a way to change the subview or reload the main view?

The code I'm using for the main view is:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var showMenu = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        if(subview1Selected){
            return AnyView(SubView1())
        } else if (subview2Selected){
            return AnyView(SubView2())
        }
        else {
            return AnyView(
            Button(action: {
                showMenu = true
            })
            {
                Text("Button")
            }
                .sheet(isPresented: $showMenu, content: {
                    MenuView()
                })
            )
        }
    }
```

the code I'm using for the pop-up sheet that is used like a menu is:

```
struct MenuView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    var body: some View {
        List{
            Button(action: {
                subview1Selected = true
                subview2Selected = false
                self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            })
            {
                Text("Subview1")
            }
            
            Button(action: {
                subview2Selected = true
                subview1Selected = false
                self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            })
            {
                Text("Subview2")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The subviews are:

```
struct SubView1: View {
    
    @State var showMenu = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            showMenu = true
        })
        {
            Text("SubView1")
        }
            .sheet(isPresented: $showMenu, content: {
                MenuView()
            })
    }
}
```

and:

```
struct SubView2: View {
    
    @State var showMenu = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            showMenu = true
        })
        {
            Text("SubView2")
        }
            .sheet(isPresented: $showMenu, content: {
                MenuView()
            })
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you declare subview1Selected? I guess that’s the problem. Because if it’s not a State variable or something alike, the main view won’t be updated on change

Comment: Try to use binding passed inside MenuView and enum as model instead of two bools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to do. You can pass the @State showMenu variable as a @Binding variable into the menu. You can use a Bool if you only have 2 views, but it's more practical to use a custom enum, which I added for you. Also, the menu button should probably be separate from the subviews.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    enum SubViewOption {
        case subview1
        case subview2
    }
    
    @State var showMenu = false
    @State var subviewSelected: SubViewOption?
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack() {
            switch subviewSelected {
            case .subview1:
                SubView1()
            case .subview2:
                SubView2()
            default:
                Text("Select a view to begin.")
            }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .overlay(
            Button(action: {
                showMenu.toggle()
            }, label: {
                Text("Menu")
                    .padding()
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .background(Color.gray.cornerRadius(30))
                    .padding()
            })
            , alignment: .bottom
        )
        .sheet(isPresented: $showMenu, content: {
            MenuView(subviewSelected: $subviewSelected)
        })
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

struct MenuView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @Binding var subviewSelected: ContentView.SubViewOption?
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            
            Button(action: {
                subviewSelected = .subview1
                presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }, label: {
                Text("Subview1")
            })
            
            Button(action: {
                subviewSelected = .subview2
                presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }, label: {
                Text("Subview2")
            })
        }
    }
}

struct SubView1: View {
        
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.red
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            
            Text("THIS IS SUBVIEW 1")
                .foregroundColor(.white)
        }
    }
}

struct SubView2: View {
        
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.blue
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            
            Text("THIS IS SUBVIEW 2")
                .foregroundColor(.white)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, that was exactly what I  was trying to do